# Why I it can't resolve 'Instance' invocation when I try initialize Unit IAP?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my code

```
var builder = ConfigurationBuilder.Instance(StandardPurchasingModule.Instance());
```

i get this error message:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Instance'

Can somebody explain why this happens and what to do about it?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Purchasing.UnityPurchasing.Initialize.html

Comment: Improved formatting and wording

Comment: do you have `using UnityEngine.Purchasing;` at the top of your file?